# translateX and translateY defined multiple times in one transform style

Tags: css-animations, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

Here is piece of animated style code for a pinch action with React Native gesture handler 2.x/React Native reanimated 2.x.

```
export default Swipe = ({route, navigation}) => {
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
    const translationX = useSharedValue(0);
    const translateX = useSharedValue(0);
    //pinch
    const scale = useSharedValue(1);
    const focalX = useSharedValue(0);
    const focalY = useSharedValue(0);

    const pinch = useMemo(() => Gesture.Pinch()
    .onUpdate((event) => {
      //console.log("pinch event : ", event);
      scale.value = event.scale;
      focalX.value = event.focalX;
      focalY.value = event.focalY;
    })
    .onEnd((event) => {
      scale.value = withTiming(1);
    })
    .simultaneousWithExternalGesture(pan)   //work together with pan gesture
  );
     const pinchStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
          return {
            transform: [
              { translateX: focalX.value },
              { translateY: focalY.value },
              { translateX: -width / 2 },  //<<===defined again
              { translateY: -height / 2 },  //<<==defined again
              { scale: scale.value },
              { translateX: -focalX.value },  //<<==
              { translateY: -focalY.value },  //<<==
              { translateX: width / 2 },  //<<==
              { translateY: height / 2 },  //<<==
            ],
          };
        }, []);
  }
```

I am not an expert on animation and not sure why both translateX and translateY were defined multiple times in `pinchStyle`. Is it describing a animated process with element starting with position at focalX/focalY, move to -width/2/-height/2, and scale (to scale.value), then to -focalX/-focalY and ends up back to the center of the screen (width/2/height/2)?